# Which version of Xcode do I have to use for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-yosemite

I'm new to iOS development.

The minimum version of iOS I'm planning is 7.0 though I'm using Xcode 7.3 under El Capitan. Xcode 7.3 even does not provide iOS simulator 7.0.

Do I have to revert back to Yosemite and use a lower version of Xcode?

If so, please recommend a proper version of Xcode.

Comment: You can use Xcode 7.3 just fine.

Comment: Would be nice to have the simulator for iOS 7, though.

Comment: How do I install iOS 7 simulator using Xcode 7.3?

Comment: You can't install iOS 7 Simulators in Xcode 7.3. Use a real device with iOS 7 if you wish to support iOS 7. But why bother with iOS 7 at this point in time? iOS 10 will be out in beta in less than 2 months.

Comment: Most apps of my competitors and famous apps support up to iOS 7.0 and many users have iOS 7 running. If I have a real device with iOS 7, I don't have to have a lower version of Xcode? I'm currently developing in Xcode 7.3

Comment: Enterprise clients often specifying 3 versions backwards compatibility because they are running under assumptions about software and devices based on old models of doing things. Usually from the Windows enterprise world. Part of negotiating with such a client is educating them on the world of devices (most especially iOS) which my be quite different to what they are used to. If you allow them to dictate support for iOS versions older than currently supported by Xcode then you are going to have problems. I've been there. it's not worth it.

Comment: Xcode 7.3 will let you support back to iOS 4.3 so supporting back to iOS 7.0 is no problem. You just need real devices to be able to test the older versions of iOS so you can be sure you aren't mistakenly using newer APIs on older versions of iOS.

Comment: citation needed, but this might help you decide whether to support iOS 7 https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/